# Full outer self join with date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table contains weekly data, with a column to identify when the data was loaded in the week.
This is the sample data

```
====================
Load_Date   |Code
====================
1 Oct 2018  |875465
8 Oct 2018  |875465
15 Oct 2018 |875465
```

Additionally, this table has data for all 52 weeks, so if I do a `DISTINCT Load_Date`, it gives me 52 rows with each week's date.

I am trying to join the table with itself such that I can identify the weeks `where Code IS NULL`. 
The query that I tried forming is

```
SELECT * FROM 
(--Query to get all distinct weeks
    SELECT DISTINCT LOAD_DATE FROM ztable
) dates
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CODE, LOAD_DATE
    FROM ztable
) z
    ON z.LOAD_DATE = dates.LOAD_DATE
```

I have tried using Left Join too but the number of records against each `code` is the number of rows that the `code` has in the table, not 52. 
For example, if the `code` has 3 rows then I'll see only 3 rows with this join.

What am I missing?

Comment: Specify some sample data for both tables, and the expected result!

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: `1 Oct 2018` <-- are you storing your dates as text?

Comment: Why does your query not include any reference to the `code` column or to `NULL`?   Your attempt doesn't fit your question at all.   It's confusing and unclear.   It's also unclear what result you are trying to get.

Comment: @TabAlleman It's just a sloppy question.  They refer to `Code` and then use `EMP_CODE` in the SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to find `code`/`load_date` combinations that don't exist.  Going by your *description* (not the sample code), I think this is:

```
select d.load_date, c.code
from (select distinct load_date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct code from t) c left join
     t
     on d.load_date = t.load_date and c.code = t.code
where t.code is null;
```